# How to write the onclick functionality for the dynamic button in meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, meteor

```
 <template name="actionTemplate">

     {{#each action}}

        <button class="myButton" id={{_id}}>btn</button>

    {{> action}}
    {{/each}}
</template>


 <template name="action">
    <div class="sct" id={{_id}}>
    some text has to display
    </div>
    </template>
```

for the above line how do I write click function to hide the "btn" button.

Answer (score 0):

If your template is named say `actionTemplate`, you should write a event function as

```
Template.actionTemplate.events({
"click .myButton" : function(event){
       var id= event.currentTarget.id;
       $('#'+id).hide();
});
```

This should do the job.

Comment: Thanks for your response.I have one more question .I have edited the code regarding to that. When I click on dynamic button in the Action template, the button should hide and display the content in the below template for that particular button. Not for all buttons at a time. How do I write click function for that?

Comment: The answer which you have send hides the entire data but it should hide only the particular button on which the button clicks

Comment: You can variables to the template while calling. May be you can try this to implement that. YOu should open another question for this issue and maybe include some screenshots. If the original question in this thread is solved can you please mark this answer as 'accepted' if this helped.